# Count Specific name of user and print only one time in php laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

in database the name X have 10 entries . But i want to Print X only one time

in this code i have states and multiple data against the states ...i print only first row against each states.

```
 <?php
                    foreach ($states_cat as $i){?>
                       <?php  $temp = json_decode($i->state); ?>

                       <?php if(!empty($states_name)){ foreach ($states_name as $index){?>

                       <?php if(!empty($temp)){foreach ($temp as $key =>
                       $keyvalue) { if($keyvalue==$index->id){?>
                                  
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                        
                        
                            <a href="{{url($i->cate_url)}}">
                            
                            <p>{{$index->states}}</p>
                            
                            
                            </a> 
                        </div>
                       
                       
                       <?php } } } } } } ?>
```

Comment: Just a note, since you're using Laravel, you should use the [Blade templates](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/blade) to make your page look cleaner

Comment: why not getting unique records from your eloquent ?

Comment: show your db structure